# Latest episode of the big bang theory, vanity card.

Tags: soft-question, recreational-mathematics, popular-math

I usually don't read these, but this time I did, and this was the card:

[image]

Does the last mathematical symbols have any meaning? I get that the equal 150.6+V, is there any more meaning behind this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $V$ is the roman numeral for $5$.  If you compute the expression, it evaluates to $500$.